# Why does my window scroll function fire up everytime i load page instead of onchange?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the scroll to only occur after I select an option. But why is the scroll being triggered every time I load page instead?

```js
 
function search2() { window.scrollTo({
  top: 300,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
}); };
```

```html
<select id = "make" onchange="search2();">
<option>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it actually does **not** fire on page load

Comment: Does the URL in your browser end on `#make`?

Answer (score 0):

i have tested your code but didnt notice what you said but for firing `onchange` event you have to use more than one option like so :

```
<select id = "make" onchange="search2();">
<option>Audi</option>
<option>BMW</option>
</select>

<script>  
function search2() { window.scrollTo({
  top: 300,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
}); };    
</script>
```

you can check my example too https://jsfiddle.net/kv263oyn/